# Chrome extension will not execute

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I have tried to implement a very basic Chrome extension that fires an alert when page loads. I cannot figure out what I am doing wrong and stripped it back to absolute basics.

The manifest is as follows:

```
{
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "name": "Force",
    "description": "This is totally basic",
    "version": "1.0",
    "content_scripts": [{
        "matches": ["http://www.google.com/*"],
        "js": [ "myscript.js"]
    }]
}
```

And the myscript.js file is:

```
<script>
    alert('fired');
</script>
```

I go to google.com and see nothing, including if a look at a search result page to try to get pattern matched. Where have I gone wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`myscript.js` should contain only the JavaScript code, no `<script>` tags.
Remove the tags.